# Black horizontal lines appearing across laptop screen

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card

Took delivery of a brand new laptop yesterday with the following specs:

> Metabox Prime P640RE
>
> 14.0" FHD 1920x1080 Matte 60Hz LED
>
> Nvidia GeForce GTX 970M with 3GB GDDR5 VRAM
>
> Intel Core i7-6700HQ Processor (6M Cache up to 3.50 GHz)
>
> 32GB DDR4 2400MHZ (2 x 16GB)
>
> Intel 540S 480GB SATA 3 M.2 SSD
>
> HGST 1TB 5400RPM Slim Line HDD
>
> Intel 8260 AC Dual Band WIFI/BT
>
> Win 10 Home 64BIT

Unpacked it, started using it, only to find black horizontal lines appearing across the screen sporadically. I updated all drivers, downloaded and installed all Windows updates but to no avail. Screenshots:

First screenshot

[image: 1st screenshot]

Second screenshot

[image: 2nd screenshot]

Third screenshot

[image: 3rd screenshot]

Some points to note:

- I had the laptop connected to the TV screen and the lines appeared on
  the TV as well, thus suggesting it's not a screen issue.
- Because it's a sporadic and somewhat rare event, I can't say whether
  the lines appear during a particular operation/screen or
  anytime/anywhere.

I've done a bit of poking around on the net and found that usually the culprit is the graphics card, but not sure. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to boot in Safe mode to see if the issue remains?

Comment: Presumably it is still under warranty? Take it back and get a replacement.